# Installation error when trying to install Tensorflow for AMD GPU. What could be the cause?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, installation, deep-learning

Currently following the [guide](https://saturncloud.io/blog/using-keras-tensorflow-with-amd-gpu/) to install tensorflow-rocm as I want to train using RX 580 GPU. However, I encounter this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow-rocm (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution
> found for tensorflow-rocm

Does anyone know how do I resolve this error? Python version is 3.9.13 (installed x64 version)

Update:
I tried installing conda and tried [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-windows) from Microsoft to install tensorflow for AMD but I am encountering the same error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow-directml (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for tensorflow-directml

Not sure what the problem is. Pip is also already upgraded.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Include the *actual* text. (Unless SO then tells you there's an existing answer)

Comment: I tried both with Windows and Linux, with the command `pip3 index versions tensorflow-rocm` to get available versions, on Windows I get None (same error as for you), on Linux there is a bunch of versions. So it seems there is no Windows support for this package with pip.

Comment: Weird because AMD provided a guide but maybe it really is for Linux. Also Microsoft provided guide for `tensorflow-directml`. What is your python version? Perhaps I need to downgrade.

Comment: I downgraded Python version from 3.9 to 3.7 and I'm now able to install tensorflow-directml. It seems that it doesn't work for the newer versions. As for the tensorflow-rocm, still unable to use for Windows.